# email_verfier gem not working returns false on require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install email_verifier gem in my rails project.

https://rubygems.org/gems/email_verifier

Gemfile

```
gem 'email_verifier', '~> 0.1.0'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

rails c

```
require 'email_verifier'
```

return false

```
result = EmailVerifier.check('example@example.com')
```

returns

```
EmailVerifier::OutOfMailServersException: Unable to connect to any one of mail servers for example@example.com
from /Users/jack/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/email_verifier-0.1.0/lib/email_verifier/checker.rb:46:in `rescue in connect'
Caused by EmailVerifier::OutOfMailServersException: Unable to connect to any one of mail servers for example@example.com
from /Users/jack/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/email_verifier-0.1.0/lib/email_verifier/checker.rb:42:in `connect'
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I am using ruby 2.5.8 and rails 5.1

Comment: a) This gem was last updated 8 years ago. b) example.com is a test domain and has no associated mail server.

Comment: even if I do it with abc@yahoo.com it still returns the same error.

Comment: @dbugger I think the main issue is require 'email_verifier' returns false. It should return true

Comment: @dbugger can you suggest any other gem then checks if the given email address exists in the real world or not without sending any email to the email address

Comment: Short answer — repeated from your question yesterday— no.

Comment: Note that you're still better of just sending an email and looking for bounce-back. This gem is far from fool-proof, many mail servers will ignore attempts to verify the existence of email addresses because this is invasive to people's privacy and prone to abuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `require 'email_verifier'` returns false

That's because it's already automatically required, and this is what `require` does when you require something already required: return `false`.

> `EmailVerifier.check('example@example.com')` returns `EmailVerifier::OutOfMailServersException`

The gem is working as intended. The entire point of this gem is that it tries to contact the mail servers for a given address to verify that A) the mail servers exist and B) that the servers acknowledge the existence of the address.

`example@example.com` is *not* a real email address, and the Gem can prove this, because there is no mail server at `example.com`. There actually cannot be, because `example.com` is one of the domains (along with `example.org`, `example.net` and `example.edu`) reserved by the IANA for use in documentation, nobody can own them or their DNS records: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com

So, when it tries to query DNS for MX records for `example.com`, it gets back an empty response and raises the error you're seeing.

Try checking with a real email address.

---

Edit:

Looking through the [source code](https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier/blob/9ac6bc7135452b307fd292618ff83b532391638e/lib/email_verifier/checker.rb#L32), if you're actually using `example.com`, then you *should* be getting a different error:

> raise EmailVerifier::NoMailServerException.new("#{domain} does not exist")

The error you're getting (`OutOfMailServersException`) happens [further down](https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier/blob/9ac6bc7135452b307fd292618ff83b532391638e/lib/email_verifier/checker.rb#L39) where the gem is able to find one or more MX records, but none of them can be contacted. The domain `example.com` should *never* return MX records, so either you're using a version of the gem that behaves differently or the actual email you're using to produce this error is not `example@example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [docs](https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier#important-problems-when-using-locally):

> **Important: problems when using locally**
>
> When you're trying to use it from an IP that a server either cannot reach or trust (in any way) - then it returns 421 service not available (connection refused, too many connections) instead of letting you connect. Because of this you should most probably always be using it on a machine that the other SMTP server can reach.